# Array of my model is send TypeError undefined in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm beginner in Angular (I use version 6). For improving my experience I've created a little web application. So, I have an error which I don't understand.
So, I have a model called "Spot" :

```js
export class Spot {
    photo: string;

    title: string;
    descri: string;
    type: string;
    lat: number;
    lng: number;

    constructor(public titleSpot: string,
                public description: string,
                public typeSpot: string,
                public latitude: number,
                public longitude: number,
            ) {
        this.title = titleSpot;
        this.descri = description; 
        this.type = typeSpot;        
        this.lat = latitude;  
        this.lng = longitude; 
    }
}
```

Following this model I have a class that connects (correctly) to a Firebase database, in order to retrieve several stored spots. I am in the TypeScript file from the `ngOnInit ()`, so that it is done at initialization if I understood correctly.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSpots();
}
```

My getSpots () method returning the error:

> **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'spots' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'spots' of
>   undefined**

I d'ont understand why.

So, voilà my method getSpots :

```js
getSpots() {
   return new Promise(
     (resolve, reject) => {
       firebase.database().ref('/spots/').once('value').then(
         (snapshot) => {
           snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
             var key = childSnapshot.key;
             var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          console.log(childData.titleSpot);
          console.log(childData.description);
          console.log(childData.typeSpot);
          console.log(childData.latitude);
          console.log(childData.longitude);
 
          this.spots.push(new Spot(childData.titleSpot,
           childData.description, childData.typeSpot, childData.latitude, childData.longitude));
           });
           resolve(snapshot.val());
         }, (error) => {
           reject(error);
         }
       );
     }
   );
 }
```

I do not understand why my Spot Array (spots) is considered undefined when I said it like this:

```
public spots: Spot[];
```

And here is the method where I will want to recover my spots :

```html
<div class="container">
    <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
        <agm-marker [iconUrl]="'assets/marker_your_location.png'" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>

         <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of mySpot; let i=index" [latitude]="mySpot.latitude[i]" [longitude]="marker.longitude[i]"  [iconUrl]="'assets/marker_spot.png'"></agm-marker>
        
         <agm-marker-cluster>
          <agm-marker *ngFor="let spot of spots" [latitude]="spot.latitude" [longitude]="spot.longitude"></agm-marker>
      </agm-marker-cluster>
    </agm-map>
</div>
```

Sorry for my english ! And thanks for everything !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is beacause of, you are using javascript function in **forEach** and in javacript function **this** will not work, so instead of normal function you have to use fat arrow function

here's is an example,

**change is here**

> snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => { });

```
public spots: Spot[] = [];

getSpots() {
   return new Promise(
     (resolve, reject) => {
       firebase.database().ref('/spots/').once('value').then(
         (snapshot) => {
           snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
             var key = childSnapshot.key;
             var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          console.log(childData.titleSpot);
          console.log(childData.description);
          console.log(childData.typeSpot);
          console.log(childData.latitude);
          console.log(childData.longitude);

          this.spots.push(new Spot(childData.titleSpot,
           childData.description, childData.typeSpot, childData.latitude, childData.longitude));
           });
           resolve(snapshot.val());
         }, (error) => {
           reject(error);
         }
       );
     }
   );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! So now I have this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined why I can't push ?

Comment: public spots: Spot[] = []; use this.. accordingly answer also updated

Comment: Glad to help you :)) please approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize spots with an empty array,

```
public spots: Spot[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer.

Your class Spot have the following:

```
photo: string;
title: string;
descri: string;
type: string;
lat: number;
lng: number;
```

To instantiate your variable spot as array, you need to do this:

```
public spot: Spots[] = [];

spot.push({photo: "", title: "", descri: "", type: "", lat: 0, lng: 0  });
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I want an array of Spot, thanks for your answer

Comment: ah ok.

var spots: Spots[] = new Spots[];

spots.push({photo: "", title: "", descri: "", type: "", lat: 0, lng: 0 });

Answer (score 0):

I would like to correct few things in your code:

When you use `public propName` in `constructor`, it will create new property on that class and assign it that value, therefor, your Spot class has every property duplicated. Here is correct way

```
export class Spot {
    photo: string;

    constructor(public title: string,
            public description: string,
            public type: string,
            public lat: number,
            public lng: number,
    ) {
        //  other code...
    }
}
```

is same as

```
export class Spot {
    photo: string;

    public title: string
    public description: string
    public type: string
    public lat: number
    public lng: number

    constructor(title: string, description: string, type: string, lat: number, lng: number) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description= description;
        this.type= type;
        this.lat= lat;
        this.lng= lng;

        //  other code...
    }
}
```

Your class that implements `getSpots` will need to have this too: `public spots: Spot[]`.

Use const when you never reasign the value, as it is better for performance and readability. `firebase.database().ref('/spots/').once('value')` returns promise by itself, therefor no need to wrap it.

```
getPosts() {
    return firebase.database().ref('/spots/').once('value').then(snapshot => {
        return Array.from(snapshot).map(childSnapshot => {
            const key = childSnapshot.key;
            const childData = childSnapshot.val();

            return new Spot(childData.titleSpot, childData.description, childData.typeSpot, childData.latitude, childData.longitude);
         });
    );
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But for the method getPosts I just want to fill my Array of Spot. So, your code return this error : TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function
TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function

Comment: Could you try this alternative, I am not completely familiar with firebase

Comment: Mark it as accepted, if it works. But also, try to understand my changes ;)